# PHP FORM reload into load div

Tags: php, jquery, forms, event-listener

I use a Jquery function to Load Php Content into a div on the Indexpage(Kinda like a masterpage) But I have to make an email form( I use a submit button) but now i want it to reload in the div and not the whole page?

This is my Menu Script(Kinda tried all sort of things)
This is all located on the INDEX PAGE.PHP

```
      $('.menut').click(function () {
       var phpFile = $(this).attr('id') + '.php';
       $('#box1').load(phpFile, function () {


               $('#contactForm').click(function (e) {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   var data = $(this).serialize();
                   $('#box1').load($(this).attr('action'), data);


   });
});
```

This is located on the Form.php page

> ```
>    <form id="contactform" method="POST" action="insch.php">
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
$('#contactform').submit(function (e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#box1').load(....)// 
   return false;
});
```

This will say when form is submitted, stop the browser from doing it's default action, then return false, to stop any other actions if any.

Comment: With this it just blocks everything I had it return a JS alert? is there any possibility I could get a confirmation that the Action actualy happend?

Comment: on chrome check the network tab, but I left the .load un complete, to let you do the extra bit ... that would not work as it is...

Comment: @ThomasBillet you are preventing the default action and the form isn't being submitted just use an ajax call to reload an element and not the entire page if you need more clarification i m more than happy to help just comment on the answer above :)